# Remote Debugging in VS2010 - access denied

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I have VS2010 on my dev machine (Win7) and I run a virtual machine under XP SP3 (name PC), on which I installed the VS2010 remote debugger, as well as .Net Framework 4.

On both OS I have the same user name (User), with the same password, with admin privilege, who is allowed to debug programs (Local Policy/User Rights Assignment/Debug programs). The firewall is deactivated on both.

When I debug my program through VS2010 (specifying "Start external program" and "Use remote machine"), I get

> Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.
>
> Access is denied. Can not connect to Microsoft Visual Studio Remote
>   Debugging Monitor on the remote computer.

On the VM the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor displays a line saying "PC\User connected".

If I try to attach a process using "Default" as transport and "User@PC" as qualifier, I get a similar error

> Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging
>   Monitor named 'User@PC'. Access is denied. Can not connect to
>   Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor on the remote
>   computer.

Again on the VM the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor displays a line saying "PC\User connected".

If I try to attach a process using "Remote (Native only with no authentication)" as transport and "PC:4015" as qualifier (changing the "Authentication mode" to "No Authentication (native only)", then it works and I see all the available processes on the VM.

Any idea on why the access is denied even if the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor seems to accept the connection? Also if I 1st use "Windows Authentication" and try to start the debugger, and then I try to change the "Authentication mode" to "No Authentication", I get

> Your new options can not be applied. Cannot stop server because one or
>   more users are currently connected.
>
> View Msvsmon's help for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was eventually able to make it work by doing "Run as administrator" on VS.Net 2010 (I forgot that Windows 2008 and 7 are quite different when it comes to right management).